# How to integrate rasa chatbot for one to one live chat

Tags: javascript, python, rasa

I have created one chatbot using Python, Rasa but getting an issue in retrieving user-id who has started to chat. Please help me with the same

Comment: Which channel? Browser or a messaging app (ie Telegram)?

Comment: Messaging app @Beppe C

Answer (score 0):

if you provide a custom action you can access the user id

```
class ActionCustom(Action):
  def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

  user_id = tracker.sender_id
```